# Wolfram Mathematica, entering differential equations

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

I am trying to model the spread of disease using the differential equations given on this site http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/loci/joma/the-sir-model-for-spread-of-disease-the-differential-equation-model with Wolfram Mathematica.

I entered:

```
 NDSolve[{i'[t]== 1/2s[t]i[t]-1/3i[t], s[t]==-1/2s[t]i[t],r[t]==1/3i[t], r[0] ==0, s[0]==1, i[0]==1.27*10^-6,s'[0]==0} i, {t, 0, 100}]
```

and received the error
NDSolve  called with  2  arguments;  3  or more arguments are expected.

I also tried

```
NDSolve[{i'[t]== 1/2s[t]i[t]-1/3i[t], s[t]==-1/2s[t]i[t],r[t]==1/3i[t], r[0] ==0, s[0]==1, i[0]==1.27*10^-6,s'[0]==0} i, {t, 0, 100}]
```

and got the same error

I am a newcomer to both differential equations and Mathematica, so I'd be grateful if someone can help.

Comment: Maybe a better fit on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: You are missing a comma in the middle of this s'[0]==0} i and if you make it s'[0]==0}, i then it works.

Answer (score 1):

As Bill told these was no coma. Second argument of NDSolve is set of function. You can type it without arguments or with arguments. Your code should look like this:

```
sol = NDSolve[
  {i'[t] == 1/2 s[t] i[t] - 1/3 i[t],
   s[t] == -1/2 s[t] i[t], r[t] == 1/3 i[t],
   r[0] == 0,
   s[0] == 1,
   i[0] == 1.27*10^-6,
   s'[0] == 0}, {i[t], s[t], r[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

It generates error connected with numerical problems:

> NDSolve::ivres: NDSolve has computed initial values that give a zero residual for the differential-algebraic system, but some components are different from those specified. If you need them to be satisfied, giving initial conditions for all dependent variables and their derivatives is recommended. >>

But you can print your results:

```
Plot[{Evaluate[i[t] /. sol], Evaluate[s[t] /. sol], 
  Evaluate[r[t] /. sol]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: solution2.png]